# Appending to QuerySet used as a __in lookup parameter

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to retrieve all posts authored by a user OR by his/her friends:

Currently, I use Q objects:

```
# friends = QuerySet containing User objects
# user = User object
posts = Post.objects.filter(Q(author__in=friends) | Q(author=user))
```

Which generates a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE ("posts_post"."author_id" IN (2, 3) OR "posts_post"."author_id" = 1)
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to append the `user` object to the `friends` QuerySet to generate a query that looks like this, instead:

```
SELECT ... WHERE "posts_post"."author_id" IN (2, 3, 1)
```

Directly using the QuerySet's .append() method does in fact work:

```
friends.append(user)
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__in=friends)
```

However, I've seen a number of answers here and elsewhere cautioning against treating QuerySets as basic lists.

Is this latter `.append()` technique safe? Is it efficient, particularly if the QuerySet is fairly large? Or is there another preferred method? Alternatively, feel free to tell me that I'm being silly and that there's nothing wrong with the Q objects approach!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querysets don't have an `append` method, so if that's working in your context `friends` is already a list rather than a queryset.

As for performance - my gut feeling is that a queryset that's too large to pull into memory so you can append to it is also going to be too large to do well as a subquery. But as always with performance questions, testing is the only real way to be sure.

You'll definitely take something of a performance hit either way. If you don't need `friends` for anything else, you could use a `values_list` queryset to get just the PKs into memory, append `user.id`, then filter on that list of PKs.

Comment: Thanks very much. Was surprised that `append` was working, but it didn't occur to me to check the object type! Also appreciate your thoughts on performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick:

```
friends = Friend.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
friends.append(user.pk)
posts = Post.objects.filter(author__in=friends)
```

As far as you save only id's, not the whole queryset this method is pretty safe.